# R fitting equation (Nikolsky-Eisenman equation) to data

Tags: r, curve-fitting, sigmaplot

I used to use *SigmaPlot* to fit a modified version of the Nikolsky-Eisenman equation of the form

```
y = P1 + P2 * log(10^(-x) + P3)
```

using the global curve fit function. Details of parameters can be found in the Sigmaplot report below. I want to do this now in R.

Some data:

```
pNO3 <- c(1.1203, 2.0410, 3.0155, 4.0048, 4.3045, 5.0, 6.0)
mV <- c(45.2, 100.9, 160.9, 215.7, 231.5, 244.5, 257.4)
data <- data.frame(pNO3, mV)
plot(data$pNO3, data$mV)
```

[image]

The graph and report generated by sigmaplot for the above data is shown below.
Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to generate something similar in R?

```
NonLinear Regression - Global Curve Fitting     Wednesday, May 01, 2013, 13:04:55
Data Source: Data 1 in Notebook1
Equation: User-Defined, Nicolsky Eisenman
f=P1+P2*log(10^(-x)+P3)
Data Set Specifications:
Data Set    Independent Variable    Dependent Variable
1           Column 3        Column 7
Global Parameters:
A Global Parameter is shared across all data sets.
Global Goodness of Fit:
R   Rsqr    Adj Rsqr    Standard Error of Estimate
0.9997  0.9994  0.9991      2.4421  
Analysis of Variance: 
Analysis of Variance: 
    DF  SS  MS  
Regression    3 264242.5551 88080.8517
Residual    4   23.8549 5.9637  
Total   7   264266.4100 37752.3443  
Corrected for the mean of the observations:
    DF  SS  MS  F   P   
Regression  2   38844.3822  19422.1911  3256.7192   <0.0001 
Residual    4   23.8549 5.9637  
Total   6   38868.2371  6478.0395   
Statistical Tests:
Normality Test (Shapiro-Wilk)           Passed  (P = 0.4003)
W Statistic= 0.9106 Significance Level = 0.0500
Constant Variance Test      Passed  (P = 0.1209)
Number of Observations =  7 
Rsqr  = 0.9994 
Residual Sum of Squares = 23.8549 
Parameter Estimates:
    Coefficient Std. Error  t   P
P1  -24.3265      3.3330    -7.2987 0.0019
P2  -61.7088      1.2861    -47.9796    <0.0001
P3  2.8351E-005   4.6040E-006   6.1579  0.0035
Fit Equation Description:
[Variables]
f0_x = col(3)
f0_y = col(7)
[Parameters]
f0_P1 = 0 ' {{previous: -24.3265}}
f0_P2 = -5 ' {{previous: -61.7088}}
f0_P3 = 0 ' {{previous: 2.8351e-005}}
[Equation]
f0 = f0_P1+f0_P2*log(10^(-f0_x)+f0_P3)
fit f0 to f0_y
[Constraints]
[Options]
tolerance=0.000100
stepsize=100
iterations=100
Number of Iterations Performed = 4
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your fitting criterion is to minimise the summed squared error, you can use `nls`, but you do need a fair starting value. I've got no idea what is reasonable for your parameters so I took a while until I copied the parameters from your sigmaplot example, which I guess were reasonable for that data set which might be similar to this data set. Anyway, if you know what the parameters mean then you can probably guess reasonable start values.

```
> start=list(P1=-24,P2=-61,P3=2.8e-5)
> m = nls(formula= mV ~ P1 + P2 * log(10^(-pNO3) + P3),data=data,start=start)
> summary(m)

Formula: mV ~ P1 + P2 * log(10^(-pNO3) + P3)

Parameters:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
P1 -1.420e+01  4.642e+00  -3.059    0.055 .  
P2 -2.732e+01  9.257e-01 -29.514 8.54e-05 ***
P3  8.417e-05  1.818e-05   4.630    0.019 *
```

You can plot the data and the smooth curve fit by creating a new set of `pNO3` measures:

```
 plot(data$pNO3,data$mV)
 newdata = data.frame(pNO3=seq(1,6,len=100))
 lines(newdata$pNO3,predict(m, newdata=newdata))
```

[image]

Note that "log" is natural logarithm in R, if you want log to base 10 then use `log10` - this changes P2 a bit, to about -62 instead of -27 as above...

With your new data and with "log10" instead of "log" in the formula expression I get:

```
> m10 = nls(formula= mV ~ P1 + P2 * log10(10^(-pNO3) + P3),data=data,start=start)
> summary(m10)

Formula: mV ~ P1 + P2 * log10(10^(-pNO3) + P3)

Parameters:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
P1 -2.433e+01  3.334e+00  -7.298  0.00187 ** 
P2 -6.171e+01  1.286e+00 -47.972 1.13e-06 ***
P3  2.835e-05  4.605e-06   6.157  0.00353 **
```

Which looks like your Sigmaplot output:

```
Parameter Estimates:
    Coefficient Std. Error  t   P
P1  -24.3265      3.3330    -7.2987 0.0019
P2  -61.7088      1.2861    -47.9796    <0.0001
P3  2.8351E-005   4.6040E-006   6.1579  0.0035
```

Comment: thanks - will have a detailed look tomorrow though first look suggests that it is not quite what I need, but it does give me a place to start. Sigma plot fitted a smooth curve and the parameters are very different from what I would expect from these data.

Comment: I have also edited the question so the data matches the Sigmaplot analyses to facilitate direct comparison

Comment: Great, that seems to work perfectly with the given data. Interesting that Sigmaplot present an` R^2` value but how valid is `R^2` for non-linear regression? Seems like a discussion for another place

Answer (score 0):

With the `"plinear"` algorithm of `nls` only the parameters that enter non-linearly need starting values.  Note that `plinear` requires a change in formula as shown to represent this model:

```
fo <- mV ~ cbind(log10(10^(-pNO3) + P3), 1)
fm <- nls(fo, data, start = c(P3 = 0), alg = "plinear")
summary(fm)
```

giving:

```
Formula: mV ~ cbind(log10(10^(-pNO3) + P3), 1)

Parameters:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
P3     2.84e-05   4.60e-06    6.16   0.0035 ** 
.lin1 -6.17e+01   1.29e+00  -47.97  1.1e-06 ***
.lin2 -2.43e+01   3.33e+00   -7.30   0.0019 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.44 on 4 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 7 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.94e-06
```

And we can plot it like this:

```
plot(data)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ pNO3, data, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]